# Get last command in VSCode terminal

Tags: python, terminal, visual-studio-code, command

I want to get the last command line in terminal that I wrote. In cases when I need to run the same line but to change a few words. In ex:

```
python manage.py startapp firstapp
```

and then I need also the same command:

```
python manage.py startapp secondapp
```

How to find this shortcut in keyboard Shortcuts in Preferences so that I don't have to type the whole thing again? Not sure how it's officially called. I found some that are Terminal: Select to Previous Command and Scroll to Previous Command.

Comment: Have you tried the *Arrow up* in the terminal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrow-Up key always gets all you the last command you wrote

Comment: Oh, I always tried diffent keys + Arrow Up, thanks :D